# Visual Studio Web API default template with no changes does not run properly

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

When creating a new ASP.Net Web Application (.Net Framework) - Web API project in Visual Studio 2017 i am having some issues. I haven't changed a single thing in the project, and it should be able to compile and run from just the template code that was generated. Yet whenever i run the project i get a Object Reference cannot be null error, but the application seemlingly keeps running. It never opens a browser automatically (Which it seems like it should from other posts) and if i try to access the URL from Postman i get Resource not found errors every time.
It seems like IIS could be the problem but i haven't messed around with that before.
I am working on an remote desktop through Citrix if that may have any implications with running web API's on localhost.
Thanks.

Comment: I dont think we can help with this one. You would need to talk to your citrix people to see what they have locked down or permitted

Comment: On which object do you get null reference exception? It might help to know in order to pinpoint your problem

Comment: If you're running in Visual Studio, the output of the application is logged to the Output Window in Visual Studio (select `ASP.NET Core Web Server" from the "Show output from" dropdown. There, you should see some specific exception(s) with traces. We'll need that info to help you further.